# Padding distorting edges of image?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I read that deep learning algorithms apply zero padding before applying filters to matrices, but does this not distort the edge of images, especially if the filtered image is reused?

Not sure if I am wrong, but I think that the edges of the image will keep decreasing in value when the filter is applied to the parts of it that are zero padded, thus when repeated this will cause the 'zero border' to increase in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation you talk about is common in the field of **Convolutional Neural Networks** when the applied kernel of a layer is larger than 1x1. In this case the edge pixels would be cut off to produce the resulting feature maps. This is not necessarily a problem. Some architectures like [U-Net](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) account for this by carefully defining the initial image size, so operations like MaxPooling are dealing with even input dimensions. Most of the time padding is applied to convolutional layers because it makes it much easier to deal with different types of resolutions. Input and Ouput will have the same spatial resolution.

As you pointed out, this means some extra processing for the edges in order to not falsify the values. One way is to use zero padding and dividing by an adjusted number of relevant pixels. For example, if a 3x3 kernel calculates the corner value of a feature map, it would cover 5 pixels of the padding and 4 pixels of the actual image.

[image]

Therefore the last step of the operation is not to divide by 9 as we usually would, but to divide by 4 because only 4 relevant pixels are currently covered by the kernel.

Another approach is to use a padding where the edge pixel values are copied to the new border. This is why in Keras for example it is referred to as `padding='same'`.